# Deep copy of ArrayList

Tags: java

I need to make a deep copy of an ArrayList of type long for both accessor and mutator methods. I've tried to search this up, but no matter what I find and try, my tests show that the mutator is not deep copying the ArrayList. This ArrayList is called "transactions" which is contained in a subclass of "CustomerData", which superclass is "PersonData".

Here is my mutator:

```
    public ArrayList<Long> getTransactions() {
        if (transactions == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();


        final ArrayList<Long> copy = new ArrayList<Long>(transactions.size());
        for(Long l : transactions) {
            copy.add(new Long(l.intValue()));
        }
        return copy;
    }
```

What about it is incorrect?

Comment: Since you are cloning a `Long`, shouldn't it be `copy.add(new Long(l.longValue()));`?

Comment: That's what it already is..

Comment: It clearly says `copy.add(new Long(l.intValue()));` in your question. This might cause a problem when the numbers in the ArrayList are above or below the int limits.

Comment: The test only uses values below 10, so I don't think it will interfere with my method.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning the objects before adding them. For example, instead of `newList.addAll(oldList);`

```
for(Person p : oldList) {
    newList.add(p.clone());
}
```

Assuming `clone` is correctly overriden in`Person`.

Comment: This gives the error: "The method clone() from the type Object is not visible" even though the clone in superclass is public

Answer (score 0):

Longs are immutable, so you don't have to worry about cloning them.

```
List<Long> transactions = Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L);

List<Long> copy = new ArrayList<>(transactions);
```